# Firebase user no longer anonymous after calling updateProfile() method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Within the Android app I create an anonymous user, and later migrate this user's data to a Google/Facebook auth account when the user decides to sign-in.

This has been working fine until using the FirebaseAuth updateProfile() method, whereafter the user is no longer anonymous when you call the isAnonymous() method.

**From the Firebase API docs** - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#isAnonymous() :

> **isAnonymous():**
>
> Returns true if the user is anonymous; that is, the user account was
>   created with signInAnonymously() and has not been linked to another
>   account with linkWithCredential(AuthCredential).

**FirebaseUser updateProfile() method:**

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updateProfile(
                UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName("Anonymous User")
                .build())
```

The above method is called so that later in the app I can check the anonymous user's display name and write it to the database etc.

According to the API docs a user is considered anonymous until such stage that **linkWithCredential()** is called or the user signs in with an auth provider method, so why does the updateProfile() method make the anonymous user no longer anonymous?

Comment: *firebaser here* Just setting the display name of a user should not change their anonymous status. This might be a bug. We're digging around to see where it comes from, when it was introduced.

Comment: Glad to have helped, Frank! Thanks for taking the time to check the bug out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is a bug in the Firebase Android SDK. It's been there since version 9.0 was launched around I/O 2016. Now that we know about it, it will be fixed in an upcoming version (although I don't know which version that will be yet).